# What does the following Makefile/shell/sed line do?

Tags: shell, sed, makefile, fullcalendar

This line is straight from FullCalendar (a jQuery plugin) [Makefile](https://github.com/mooballit/fullcalendar/blob/master/Makefile). I can't make sense of it, in particular the part with the dollar sign. I don't know whether make, the shell or sed "processes" it. I'm also unclear about other (apparently?) sed commands.

```
DEMO_RE = (<script[^>]*_loader\.js[^>]*><\/script>|<!--\[\[|\]\]-->)[^<]*
DEMO_SED = sed -nE '1h;1!H;$${;g;s/${DEMO_RE}//g;p;}'
```

1. What does 1h do?
2. Where and how are/is the dollar sign and brackets interpreted?
3. What does the first g command and the last p command (to print?) do?

Answer (score 8):

That's quite a bezoar.

`DEMO_RE` is a regular expression. Loosely speaking, that means it's a description of another sequence of characters. Any given sequence of characters either does or does not match this regular expression.

`DEMO_SED` is a sed command. At this stage, it is simply a Make variable, a sequence of characters, but later on it can be passed to the shell (after variable expansion by Make), which will interpret it as a sed command.

I don't entirely understand this sed command, but here's my best attempt. Starting from the middle:

```
sed 's/${DEMO_RE}//'
```

Make will expand `${DEMO_RE}` to the string of gobbledegook in the first line, look for a match with whatever line of text is being considered, and change the matching text to nothing (i.e. delete it).

```
sed 's/${DEMO_RE}//g'
```

The `g` modifier to the `s` command means make the substitution (in this case deletion) on all matches, not just the first one found.

```
sed -nE 's/${DEMO_RE}//g;p'
```

The `-n` means do not print the result by default. The `p` means print the contents of the pattern space, so for the moment these changes cancel each other out. The `E` means interpret regular expressions as extended regular expressions, not basic regular expressions.

```
sed -nE '{s/${DEMO_RE}//g;p}'
```

The curly braces group these commands.

```
sed -nE '${;g;s/${DEMO_RE}//g;p;}'
```

Now things get complicated. Sed has a second buffer called the hold space. The `g` command copies the contents of the hold space into the patterns space (which is the buffer people usually use and the the only one most people know about). This doesn't make much sense until we consider the other commands that will put things *into* the hold space. The `$` means that this command (the contents of the curly braces) should be applied only when sed reaches the last line of the input. **I don't see any purpose to the leading semicolon, but I don't dare say it does absolutely nothing.** For now I'll omit the substitution command for legibility.

```
sed -nE '$${;g;p;}'
```

Since Make tries to expand things starting with `$`, and we want to pass a '$' intact to sed, we escape it with another '$'. Make will expand `$$` into `$` and pass `${...` to the shell (which will pass it to sed).

```
sed -nE '1h;1!H;$${;g;p;}'
```

The `1h` means copy the first line of input to the hold space. The `1!H` means append every line *other than* the first one to the hold space. Remember the `-n`; nothing will be printed until sed executes the group of commands in the curly braces, which will happen only when the last line of input has been read in. So:

```
sed -nE '1h;1!H;$${;g;s/${DEMO_RE}//g;p;}'
```

"Read all of the input into the hold space, printing nothing, then pull it all back at the end, excise everything that matches the (possibly extended), and print whatever's left."

This answer's getting pretty long; I could give you a rough translation of the regex, but doing that in a way that won't confuse this medium is a pain. It seems to want to match anything surrounded by `script` tags or `<!--[[` or `]]-->`, and all that follws up to the next tag.

Comment: The "leading" semicolon is actually a line division between the curly brace and the following command.  GNU sed does not require it, but virtually every other sed implementation does.  It should always be included for portability.

Comment: Oh ya, and +1 from me too.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Beta has done an excellent job of breaking apart the sed script, logical block by logical block.  The sed script removes certain blocks of JavaScript from input text.  His final summation may be all you need.  If you want an even shorter answer, here goes.

The confusing bits you mentioned were the dollar signs.

```
        ┌ Double $ is actually just an "escaped" $ character
        │       ┌ Starts a variable reference
        │       │
'1h;1!H;$${;g;s/${DEMO_RE}//g;p;}'
          │     │        │      │
          │     └variable┘      │
          └ Stuff run at EOF ───┘
```

The first pair of dollar signs make a single dollar sign, which sed interprets to mean "at the end of the file".  So the stuff between the outside curly brackets gets run at EOF.  The inner curly brackets are in the form of `${VARNAME}`, which is Make's way of referring to variables.  It LOOKS like a shell variable reference, but it's not.

In this case, because a Make variable assignment doesn't actually execute anything, your `DEMO_SED` variable is being assigned with the content of `DEMO_RE` inside it.  Ironically, reason this was split into two variables are split apart was to make the whole process more readable.  :-)

Note that none of this actually *executes* anything (i.e. sed).  It only assigns the variable.  Later on in your Makefile, you presumably have a target with a line that may look something like:

```
${DEMO_SED} path/to/file.html.orig > path/to/file.html
```

It's at that point that all of this turns into something functional.